# Laravel input array why do I get null in $request->quantity

Tags: php, laravel

After searching similar questions I still didn't get the error

The thing is that I have a form that usually works, but the 10% of the users have this error

> array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Form

```
<select name="quantity[]" class="form-control option-quantity" data-price="100">
   <option data-price="100" value="0">0</option>
   <option data-price="101" value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option data-price="102" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'quantity.*' => 'required|integer',
]); 

if ($validator->fails()) { 
   abort(500);
}

if(count($request->quantity) == 0 || array_sum($request->quantity) < 1)){
   //message to select at least a quatity
}
```

They always put an amount because I did't restrictions, js to avoid nulls or 0 and from the server side not to allow 0

So, as it happens just sometimes, I'm wondering if some explorers do something weird changing the quantity[] to quantity or null or something, I'm driving a bit crazy here and I can't reproduce the error myself and it wouldn't be a good idea to wait the error to happen to a user (:

BTW of course I can add `if($request->quantity)` to avoid the error, but that not solves the question of why I get a null just sometimes, rest is fine.

As per suggestion after doing `dd($request->quantity);` I get:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "1"
]
```

But again, for me its working good, not for the 10%.

Comment: `dd($request->quantity)` and check. Also it is `multiple` I guess.

Comment: Before  your condition do `dd($request->quantity)` and check what output is showing . Show us that output.

Comment: Cant U make !empty condition on server side also

Comment: updated the dd($request->quantity); result in the question

Comment: Are there situations where this `select` is disabled or hidden?

Comment: still, I have a validation on the server side to avoid that, javascripts to disallow 0 or null.. I updated the quetion with the controller validators

Comment: @TrOnNe did you manage to solve this? Also experiencing this one on Laravel 5.8, inputs are array (checkboxes).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply avoid this error by checking quantity.It

```
 if($request->quantity){
  if(count($request->quantity) == 0 || array_sum($request->quantity) < 1)){
   //message to select at least a quatity
  }
}
```

It is throwing this error because `$request->quantity` is null;

Hope this helps

Comment: I know, but my problem is.. why do I get null, it should be impossible

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not tagged the version of Laravel, I'll make an assumption that you are using latest version.

> why I get a null

Check your validation rule..

When a user submits the data with empty strings, Laravel makes it nullable. Checkout the middleware `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` which is located inside `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware` folder.

So, if you want it to be always present at the time of submitting the user data, make it required like so.

```
return [
    'quantity' => 'required',
    // .. other validation rules..
];
```

Comment: but how come I can get null if the user is selecting the option?? it's crazy

Comment: That's simply hard to believe.. It is getting nullified because the user is not submitting that data.. And according to the middleware, it is converting an empty string to null..

Comment: I have already that validator
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['quantity.*' => 'required|integer'].. so it's really weird

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "[]" from the name on the select, so you will have this:

```
<select name="quantity" class="form-control option-quantity" data-price="100">
   <option data-price="100" value="0">0</option>
   <option data-price="101" value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option data-price="102" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```